# How to export csv row into separate .txt file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv (export.csv) which contains almost 9k rows structured as follows:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|      Oggetto        |     valueID      | note          |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|          1          |      work1       |DescrizioneA   |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|          2          |      work2       |DescrizioneB   |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|          3          |      work3       |DescrizioneC   |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
```

I would export the rows from the column "note" in a separate .txt file and then name the file as the value from the column "valueID" i.e work1.txt (Content of the work1.txt file "DescrizioneA").
Starting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087088/how-to-extract-data-from-rows-in-csv-file-into-separate-txt-files-using-python) similar issue I tried, failing, like so:

```py
import csv

with open('export.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().split('\n')

for row in range(1, len(data)):
    third_col= data
    with open('t' +  '.txt', 'w') as output:
        output.write(third_col[2])
```

I tried then with Pandas

```py
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.read_csv("export.csv", engine ='python')

d = data
file = 'file{}.txt'

n = 0 # to number the files
for row in d.iterrows():
    with open(file.format(n), 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(row))
        n += 1
```

I'm getting something but:

1. The filename of each is progressive according to the number of the file from 1 to 9000 ex. file0001.txt
2. The content of the .txt comprises all the 3 columns plus the content of the column "note" it's partial ex: "La cornice architettonica superiore del capite..."

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please show a sample of the actual file. Is it really pipe separated, or is it a CSV?

Comment: What do you think `third_col= data` does?

Comment: Why are you opening the output file with every iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try pandas:

```
df=pd.read_csv("export.csv",sep=",")

for index in range(len(df)):
     with open(df["valueID"][index] +  '.txt', 'w') as output:
        output.write(df["note"][index])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use Pandas you can do like this

```
with open('export.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().split('\n')
```

Ok, it was good start to store your data line by line in variable

Now you need to find you data is each row. If you data is stored like you said (single word or number separated by spacebar) you can again split it:

```
text_for_file = ""
for row in range(1, len(data)):
    splitted_text = row.split(' ')
    text_for_file = '\n'.join([text_for_file, splitted_text[2]])
    #So now all you notes are stored in text_for_file string line by line
#write all you data to file
with open("your_file.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(text_for_file)
```