# Extracting csv file rows as individual .txt files

Tags: csv, corpus

I am new to Python and trying to extract certain data from rows of a csv file into individual .txt files (to create a corpus for NLP). So far I have the following:

```
import csv
with open(r"file.csv", "r+", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

t = (data[1][91])
fn = str(data[1][90])
g = open("%s.txt" %fn,"w+")
for i in range(1):
    g.write(t)
    g.close
```

Which does what I want for the 1st row, however I am not sure how to get the program to loop up to row 1047. Note: the [1] signifies row 1, the [91] & [90] should remain fixed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract data from rows in .csv file into separate .txt files using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087088/how-to-extract-data-from-rows-in-csv-file-into-separate-txt-files-using-python)

Comment: It is very similar to what i want to do, so after turning each row into a list i have tried this:

with open(r"filepath.csv", "r+", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        rownumber = 0
        for row in reader:
             g=open("t"+str(rownumber)+".txt","w")
             g.write(row)
             rownumber = rownumber + 1
             g.close()

However this does not work with the lists, but rather needs a string. If I try the solution from that link i get:

NameError: name 'x' is not defined